# How do I sanitize my profile information?

Tags: support, profile-page

I had been one of the few users still using OpenID to log in, but now that SE is ending OpenID support I entered an email and password to replace the OpenID.
Now I see that at some point in the past few years I had used Facebook to log in and it formed some kind of mutant split personality profile. Two avatars, sometimes I would see it display my real first name as a username and other times my preferred OpenID username. The SE profile page is way over complicated in my opinion.(feature bloat or poor merging of old parts?) I changed the display of my real name to my preferred username but I do not think it was the correct method and just made a weird duplicate username.

How do I sanitize my profile information to use only one user name, picture, and general profile info? (I mean truly one object, not two nearly identical copies) I just want one profile across the all SE sub-sites, how can I easily do this?

Edit to add:(The issue seems to be centered around my Stack Overflow profile, I just noticed SO has its own "meta" and some profile duality around that meta and some kind of resume-profile crammed inside, sort of like a horrible forum-profile-turducken. KISS, most users don't care about profiles beyond the most basic name, picture, and maybe location; don't build a chandelier when a candle stick will do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really "sanitize", but you can make a single profile edit apply to ALL sites on Stack Exchange where you have an account associated to the one you're editing.

To achieve this, go to the "Edit Profile & Settings" on any site, e.g. [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), edit what you want, then when done, click the "Save and copy changes to all public communities" button:

> [image]

This will save you the need to go and edit site by site.

However, the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) won't be updated, so in order to update it as well click the "Update profile info":

> [image]

Then choose a site and click "Copy".

Comment: Good enough. Thank you.

Comment: Just noticed, this method does not sync the avatar picture across sites. Could be a bug.

Comment: @MaxPower oh, think you must actually change it on a site in order for it to change on all sites. Try changing to something else then back to "real" one, if it works I'll edit the answer. :)

Comment: I uploaded a new photo(different filename really) then "Save and copy to all..." and it seems to have updated all the sites.